# How does this while-loop compute? (x = function(x))

Tags: python, while-loop, evaluation

I'm doing a quiz from "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python", and after tinkering with the problem for a bit, I finally found a solution that worked (with a little help from a comp-sci buddy of mine). The quiz asks me to make program that executes a Collatz-sequence.

I understand the logic behind all of the code, EXCEPT for the final line.

Here's my code with a few comments:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

guess = input("Your guess please ")
while guess != 1:
    guess = collatz(int(guess))
```

The output of the program is a sequence of numbers, as the while-loop somehow re-iterates over the returned value of the function, and uses that for another computation.

My problem is with the last line. Here's how I understand it:

1. Once I enter the while-loop, my function "collatz" is called, using my input-value
2. The function is run, and my input is computed, and based on the input, I get either the even or odd calculation in return
3. Here's where my brain hurts!
4. Is the line "guess = collatz(...)" now constantly updating "guess" to be equal to the retuned value from the function? If this is the case, then I completely understand the flow. If it's not the case, then I don't understand how the returned value is constantly being used for new calculations.

Also, is this what is called "recursion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes.

**Longer answer: (still short)**

The `collatz` function is returning a value which is assigned to `guess`.

Also, this is **not** called recursion, recursion is a function which calls itself.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll stumble upon the recursion-stuff later on.

Answer (score 1):

First, no, this is not a recursion. Recursion is a function that calls itself.

For instance this is a recursion:

```
def fibonacci(n):   
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
   return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

As you can see here fibonacci function will call fibonacci function ... But it also has an exit condition (n == 0, and n == 1). Without that, this would cause runtime error with message that maximum recursion depth exceeded. But if I am not mistaken, you can check what is the maximum depth of recursion with following command:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

On my computer, this number is 1000. If this number is to small for you, you can also set it with this command:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(n)
```

About other thing. Your function is returning some calculated value and in your main loop, this is assigned to variable guess. So everytime, that main loop will go through, value of guess will also update

Comment: Thank you! I'll save recursion for later. It seems a bit more complex.